# OpenCV : Detecting Uncomplete Rounded Rectangle

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

How I can detect Uncomplete Rounded Shape Card ID Using OpenCV

### Sample

[image]

I have tried `findContours` but can't get the edge points of the card, My aim is to crop the card.

### Code Used

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('./data/15430864595779441.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

binary = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)
cv2.imshow("Binary" , binary)
(contours,_) = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for contour in contours:
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)


cv2.imshow("Results" , image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Please remove the personal data from the image!

Comment: Any assumption's possible about size and position of the card in the image? E.g. the card covers at least 50% of the image area and the image center hits the inner region of the card?

Comment: how to detect ID cards is a **frequent question**. I'm sure previous questions have **useful answers**. -- I don't see how just thresholding can work here. the card does not contrast against the background. -- you could try feature matching and homography, `samples/python/find_obj.py` in OpenCV -- Hough line extraction *may* be applicable...

Answer (score 1):

I have made a piece of code to propose you a solution.

My approach is to first apply the Canny Detector to find all the edges of the image. Then, applying the Hough Transform it is possible to find all the straight lines of the thresholded image (I have implemented the code until here). Then you could extend the lines segments into complete lines to find where the lines cross having the corner of the card. (I think some preprocessing will have to be done for removing the outliers but it is possible.)

I attach the code and the outputs I've obtained:

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread('card2.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 100, 200)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, math.pi / 180.0, 100, minLineLength=100, maxLineGap=10)

plt.imshow(edges)
plt.show()

print(lines)
for x in range(0, len(lines)):
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[x]:
        cv2.line(image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)

plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

#### Mask after the Canny Edge Detector

[image: Canny]

#### Lines detected drawn on the input image

[image: Hough Transform]

Hope it works, if need something more just tell me.

#### Lines detected drawn on the example image of the comments

[image: Second Example]

Comment: Thanks for your code, I have an issue I can't detect the edges on other images like this one https://ibb.co/8r8PDrV , anything special I have to modify to make your code generic

Comment: There a lot of parameters in the piece of code and you should fine-tune them with your dateset with some kind of train/test splitting and a metric such as Intersection over Union (IoU). However, using the other image you showed in the comment I've tried with different thresholds for the Canny Detector and I accomplish good results. I recommend you taking a look on: [Canny Detector in OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html). Moreover, I attach to you the code I've changed and I've modified the answer to put the result of your image. ```edges = cv2.Canny(v, 150, 50)```